# Terminal Error I am not able to undertsand in python

Tags: python, twitter, file-io

I am trying to download 5000 tweets in a text file as part of an Assignment I have. It is giving me errors, I looked up a solution online and tried fixing it but it is not working well.

```py
import tweepy

API_KEY = ("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIQDkgEAAAAA%2B5jSmwchB7hT3%2FQ8jh4EGrpZY%2FY%3Dcn2Qvt5oqUP6y03hOywzN7WVUF97kPY27B2pUyeDPleqZvLeAu")

client = tweepy.Client(API_KEY)

query = "covid"
tfile = open("tweets.txt", "w")
response = client.search_recent_tweets(query)
for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                              query=query,
                              max_results=100).flatten(limit=5000):
  ### WRITE CODE TO SAVE these tweets into a file here.
  tweet = str(tweet) + "/n"
  tfile.write(tweet)

  tfile.close()
```

The error message I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
  File "data_collection.py", line 15, in <module>                              
    tfile.write(tweet)                                                         
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I tried looking for solutions online and reading threads. It said it was an indentattion error. I did that but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: tfile.close() is inside the for loop

Comment: You should be using a `with` statement in the first place, so that the file is automatically closed once the `with` statement completes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `with` statement to ensure that the file is closed, and closed at the proper *time*, without having to explicitly call `tfile.close`.

```
query = "covid"
response = client.search_recent_tweets(query)

with open("tweets.txt", "w") as tfile:

    for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                                  query=query,
                                  max_results=100).flatten(limit=5000):
        tweet = str(tweet) + "\n"
        tfile.write(tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the file outside the loop, I think the function `Paginator` is a generator and it is using the file so you are not able to close it